# Как убрать сниппет со ссылками в поисковой выдаче?

Tags: seo, google-search

[image: пример проблемы]

Как убрать блок, выделенный фиолетовым на скриншоте, с поисковой выдачи?
Rich spippets не были установлены.
Установленный мета-тег `<meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox" />` не помог, мета-тег с правилом nosnippet убирает дескрипшн.

Answer (score 2):

Пример, который вы показываете на вашем снимке с экрана, похож на выдачу структурированных данных для хлебных крошек. Проверьте ваши структурированные данные и попробуйте удалить хлебные крошки, если это там есть.

Дополнение 8 августа 2020 года в связи с комментарием пользователя.
Если это не структурированные данные то вы можете использовать HTML-атрибут data-nosnippet о котором **[Гугл говорит следующее](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#data-nosnippet-attr)**:

Фрагменты текста на HTML-странице можно специально пометить, чтобы они не показывались в результатах поиска. Для этого служит атрибут data-nosnippet HTML-элементов span, div и section. Атрибут data-nosnippet является логическим и может указываться без значения. Код должен отвечать стандартам HTML и содержать все необходимые закрывающие теги.

```html
<p>This text can be shown in a snippet
 <span data-nosnippet>and this part would not be shown</span>.</p>

<div data-nosnippet>not in snippet</div>
<div data-nosnippet="true">also not in snippet</div>

<div data-nosnippet>some text</html>
<!-- unclosed "div" will include all content afterwards -->

<mytag data-nosnippet>some text</mytag>
<!-- NOT VALID: not a span, div, or section -->
```

Обычно при индексировании робот Google отрисовывает страницы, но это происходит не всегда. Поэтому извлечение data-nosnippet может быть выполнено как до отрисовки, так и после нее. Чтобы избежать неопределенности, не используйте JavaScript для добавления атрибута data-nosnippet в существующие узлы или для его удаления из них. Если вы добавляете элементы в структуру DOM при помощи JavaScript, указывайте атрибут data-nosnippet в момент создания этих элементов. Если вы хотите применить data- nosnippet к нестандартным элементам, размещайте их внутри тегов div, span или section.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!
Из других источников мне удалось узнать что это Sitelinks, или другие называют это Fraggles. И удалить их на данный момент нельзя.

Comment: К сожалению, ```<div data-nosnippet>not in snippet</div>``` не помог. В моем случае, ссылки берутся из меню, я обрамила его в <div> c аттрибутом data-nosnippet (не используя JS) и решила подождать. Спустя 2-3 недели результат тот же - ссылки в поисковой выдаче остались.

Comment: Не понятно. Вы что хотите закрыть для гуглбот вашу навигацию? Если это так, то гугл может считать что это технической ошибкой, потому что это явно противоречит их руководствам для веб-мастеров. .Дайте нам знать УРЛ веб-страницы с этой проблемой.

Comment: Вы правы, я хочу полностью скрыть меню и все ссылки в нем, т.к. именно из них берется информация для для блока ссылок, показаных на примере изначально.

Я не могу дать ссылку на сайт, по соображениям NDA, но могу сказать некоторую техническую информацию, которая может помочь решить мой вопрос. Движок сайта - Wordpress, ниже оставила ссылку на скриншот меню.
https://i.ibb.co/w0QPCpJ/image-24.png

Comment: Используйте тот же самый атрибут data-nosnippet для вашего меню, который я рекомендовал в моем ответе.

Comment: Так я уже обрамила меню в <div> с аттрибутом data-nosnippet. И это не сработало. Или я вас не верно поняла.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать  data-nosnippet для каждого блока в котром установлена ссылка меню.

Comment: Спустя чуть более недели прихожу к заключению что данный метод так же не сработал.
https://i.ibb.co/hV3knHz/image-25.png
Подскажите, может есть еще какие-нибудь варианты? Например, поднять span на уровень выше, обрамив <li></li> в span.